# Retrieve values from arrays in different functions

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, global-variables

I'm trying to write a program in c where the length of an array is declared in the main function, then a function is called and allocates the memory and initalizes the values, and then the main function prints the values. I have declared the array and its length globally, but when the main function "retrieves" values from the array, I get a segfault, which, I assume, is because only the pointer on the array is global, but not the values themselves. Is there any method of solving this besides merging the functions?

Comment: Where is your code? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to write a program in c where the length of an array is declared in the main function, then a function is called and allocates the memory and initalizes the values, and then the main function prints the values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *foo(size_t len) {
    int *values = calloc(len, sizeof *values);
    if (values) {
        values[2] = 42;
    }
    return values;
}
int main(void) {
    size_t len = 5; // length of array declared in main()
    int *p = foo(len); // foo() allocates and initializes
    for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) printf("%d: %d\n", k, p[k]); // main() prints the values
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

> I have declared the array and its length globally, but when the main function "retrieves" values from the array, I get a segfault, which, I assume, is because only the pointer on the array is global, but not the values themselves.

Try to avoid globals.
Do not confuse arrays and pointers. See section 6 of [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).

> Is there any method of solving this besides merging the functions?

Yes.